# Command from docker image not passed through to pipeline

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, yarnpkg

In my `Dockerfile` of an image that is based on `node:12` I have the following lines to add a self signed certificate

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -yqq install ca-certificates
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/domain
COPY .docker/cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/domain/
RUN update-ca-certificates --fresh

RUN yarn config set cafile /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/domain/cert.crt
```

When I also add `RUN yarn config list` I can see that this setting has been added successfully. Afterwards, I built and pushed my image to the registry.

However now, when I use it in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` and use `yarn install` I get an error that there's a self-signed certificate in the chain.

When I use `yarn config list` inside the pipeline, it doesn't show the `cafile` as if the settings set in the image are not used.

When I add `yarn config set cafile /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/domain/cert.crt` to the `script` part of my pipeline it works without problems which means

1. That my image is built correctly, since it has the cert at the right location and it works if added manually
2. That somehow the config is not persisted from the image to the pipeline

I checked the `Dockerfile` https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/12/stretch/Dockerfile and there's no user set which could mean that it runs under different users, does it?

Why does it not work when adding the cert in the image already?

Answer (score 0):

Commands from the Dockerfile do not affect the host, just the image. If you use this image as your job image, you won't need to set it again.